# wp e-commerce product single page not working

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I am using wp e-commerce plugin & also used gold cart plugin for more functionality but my  product inner page not working.

There is use in grid view of products and files from plugin where being put in my own theme.
I put my wp e-commerce plugin > wpsc-components > theme-engine-v1 > templates files in my theme but it still not working. Can any one having idea about this? so please help me.

page url:-

http://www.eddingtonhousenursery.co.uk/wordpress/products-page/perennials/achillea-terracotta/

Comment: I you remove `products-page/` from the url, the page will load.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you template file is not in the right place.

Please make sure you have moved all the plugin template files in the theme.

Best way to debug is print a string and die. Now check if your printed string appears on the page.